# Spring4 MVC ModelAndView Constructor

Tags: spring-mvc

In Spring 4 MVC

In my Controller Class

```
@Controller
public class TesterController{

   @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView show(){

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("Test");
    mav.addObject("Test" , "TestObject");

    return mav;
   }

 }
```

Can some one explain how is the use of the ***ModelAndView*** class in this controller.
What is use of addObject Method
and What is use of having constructor.

Thanks in Advance
Pavan

Comment: Have you started by reading the javadoc?

Answer (score 0):

You can just look at the source as spring is open source.

The model is just a map. So the addObject, is just adding the string "TestObject", with a key of "Test".

A model and view is simply a string of the viewname, along with the associated map/model.

The view resolver will then find the appropriate view file based on viewname, and the map values can be resolved in the view using the key.

Comment: What is usefulness to write it mav.addObject("Test" , "TestObject");??? This part is not clear.

Comment: @Pavan it allows and obejct to be accessed form the map, within the view. Its is useful